# A simple function closure question -- a counter function to update count

Tags: javascript, closures

Hello I have a code here:

```
/* example counter app */

const incrCounter = () => {
    let count = 0;

  return () => {
    return ++count;
  }
}

/* now use the counter */

incrCounter()();
incrCounter()();
alert(incrCounter()()); // expect 3 but gets 1
```

I expect to get an alert that says 3 but I get 1 instead.

I got a live demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gunitinug/L9nrt085/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time `incrCounter` is called, you get a function in return which closes over a `count` variable that was just created. If you call `incrCounter` 3 times, you get 3 separate `count` variables, in different closures.

Call it *once* to get the function that closes over a single binding of `count`, then call that function 3 times, so that that one binding is incremented 3 times:

```js
const makeCounter = () => {
    let count = 0;

  return () => {
    return ++count;
  }
}

const counter = makeCounter();
counter();
counter();

console.log(counter());
```

Giving the function more accurate names will make things more understandable as well - like above, you could call the function-that-returns-a-function `makeCounter`, and call the returned function `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

The count variable should be outside the function to retain its value

```
/* example counter app */
let count = 0;

const incrCounter = () => {
  return () => {
    return ++count;
  }
}

/* now use the counter */

incrCounter()();
incrCounter()();
alert(incrCounter()());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your input guys.

On closer inspection I could do this:

```
/* example counter app */

const incrCounter = (() => {
    let count = 0;

  return () => {
    return ++count;
  }
})();

/* now use the counter */

incrCounter();
incrCounter();
alert(incrCounter());
```

Answer (score 0):

More flexible version in my opinion.

```js
const makeCounter = (count = 0) => () => ++count

const counter = makeCounter(5);

console.log(counter()); // 6
console.log(counter()); // 7
console.log(counter()); // 8
console.log(counter()); // 9
```